# How to apply function for only special cells in column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a issue with applying function for column in pandas, please see below code :

```
import pandas as pd

#create a dict as below
data_dic = {
    "text": ['hello',1,'how are you?',4],
    "odd": [0,2,4,6],
    "even": [1,3,5,7]
}
#create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
#define function
def checktext(str1):
    if isinstance(str1,str):
        return str1.upper()
def checknum(str1):
    if isinstance(str1,int):
        return str1+1

df['new'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: checktext(x))
df['new'].head()
```

my df now show like below:

```
    text           odd       even   new
0   hello          0          1     HELLO
1   1              2          3     None
2   how are you?   4          5     HOW ARE YOU?
3   4              6          7     None
```

I would like to apply function checknum for 2 cell in column 'new' which is having 'None' value. Can someone assist this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use vectorial code:

```
# make string UPPER
s = df['text'].str.upper()
            # where there was no string, get number + 1 instead
df['new'] = s.fillna(df['text'].where(s.isna())+1)
```

output:

```
           text  odd  even           new
0         hello    0     1         HELLO
1             1    2     3             2
2  how are you?    4     5  HOW ARE YOU?
3             4    6     7             5
```

That said, for the sake of the argument, your 2 functions could be combined into one:

```
def check(str1):
    if isinstance(str1,str):
        return str1.upper()
    elif isinstance(str1,int):
        return str1+1

df['new'] = df['text'].apply(check)
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, this is a sample , main issue is I would like to know how to apply for specific cell in the column in pandas. Could you assist base on my question ?

Comment: Hi @mozway, this is a sample , main issue is I would like to know how to apply for specific cell in the column in pandas. Could you assist base on my question ?

Comment: @vanthang what do you mean by "*how to apply for specific cell*"?

Comment: if there are more data types like s.isna() != int type rows

Comment: @ansev then you can use `to_numeric`.  edit: I see you have done that ;)

Comment: in my question , you see in the column 'new' , there are 2 cell value 'None' , i want to apply a different function for these cells only without impact to the existing cell in this column

Comment: @vanthang use vectorial code: `df.loc[df['new'].isna(), 'new'] = your_vector_operation`. You have plenty of examples in this Q/A ;)

Comment: @vanthang you might also need to apply the operation only on `df.loc[df['new'].isna(), 'new']`

Answer (score 0):

your function:

```
def checktext(str1):
    if isinstance(str1,str):
        return str1.upper()
```

Will return None, if the if statement is false (i.e., 'str1' is not a string). By default, return the value?

```
def checktext(str1):
    if isinstance(str1,str):
        return str1.upper()
    return str1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could use the `StringMethods` accessor to convert to upper case whithout any loop. And when you have done that, you can easily process the rows where the result is NaN:

```
df['new'] = df['text'].str.upper()
mask = df['new'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'new'] = df.loc[mask, 'text'] + 1
```

It gives directly:

```
           text  odd  even           new
0         hello    0     1         HELLO
1             1    2     3             2
2  how are you?    4     5  HOW ARE YOU?
3             4    6     7             5
```